# Regular Expression to allow a specific word and number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to write a regular expression to match **Term 1 - Mid Term Test**. The first part **[Term 1 - ]** should be mandatory. After the hyphen and a space, a user can write whatever they want. I tried

```
/Term [1-3]\s[a-zA-Z ]/
```

However, it doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

Note: there can only be 3 terms that's why I wrote `[1-3]`.

Comment: I think the reason is you have an hyphen `-` in your string and that is not included in `[a-zA-Z ]`. If you remove the hypen (Term 1 Mid Term Test) your regexp will work. Alternatively, you can just use * in place of [a-zA-Z] and this will include also special characters

Comment: Oops! Yeah, you're right... I rewrote the regex to /Term [1-3]\s-\s[a-zA-Z]+/. It's working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: `/^Term\s[1-3]\s\-\s.*/`. It also ensures the beginning of the text is as you expect

Comment: For some really weird reasons, it's not working with Angular 9 react forms... Even my initial regex isn't working, but it works in visual studio code when I try to use its regex find... Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show your code, or even better upload to StackBlitz. The regex is correct.

Comment: Done... It's working now... I found where I made a typo